# Swift load List that is not occupying the entire view, by calculating the row height

Tags: swift, swiftui, swiftui-list

Load a list with each row height dynamic based on the calculation,

> Initially, View1 will be of say (for eg:) 200 after certain operation add's a few more components to view1 now it gets to say (for eg:) 500. Same applies to all other view as well i.e View2, View3 in dynamicView

Need to set height the row in this case as List is not occupying the entire screen.
Here everything is working fine, but for the height to get changed there is a time delay.

Any recommendation please ?

```
@State var dynamicView : AnyView = [View1 , View2, View3];
@State var currentIndex : Int;

  var body: some View {
    VStack{
     Text("HI..")
    }
    List{ 
       ForEach(0..<self.currentIndex  , id: \.self){ item in
        self.dynamicView [item]
       }
    }.environment(\.defaultMinListRowHeight, 100)
    VStack{
      Text("View")
    }

   }
```

Comment: Would you prepare testable example?